# Mudar nome da id com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse código onde preciso mudar o nome de duas id quando clica em um evento do calendário

```
eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                endtime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end).format('h:mm');
                starttime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY, h:mm');
                var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
                var mywhen2 = event.id;
                $('#modalTitle_excluir').html(event.title);
                $('#modalWhen_excluir').text(mywhen);
                $('#eventID_faturar_outro').text(event.id);
                $('#id_do_form_faturar').attr('data-formid', event.id);
                $('#resultado_empresa_').attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_'+event.id);


                $('#calendarModal_excluir').modal();
            },
```

Estou utlizando isso para mudar o nome dos id

```
$('#id_do_form_faturar').attr('data-formid', event.id);
$('#resultado_empresa_').attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_'+event.id);
```

O **data-formid=""** funciona toda vez que clico em um evento abre uma modal com o id do evento (data-formid="id_evento").

No **#resultado_empresa_** também muda, mas o problema é que muda em todas as divs com o **id="resultdo_empresa"**. Como poderia fazer para que só mudasse o id do evento clicado?

Vou colocar aqui o html para poder ver a estrutura

Modal

```
<div id="calendarModal_calendar2" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title center">Detalhes da Consulta</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
            <span class="titulo_modal">Título</span>
            <h4 id="modalTitle_excluir" class="modal-title"></h4>
            <span class="titulo_modal">Data e Hora</span>
            <div id="modalWhen_excluir" style="margin-top:5px;"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <form role="form" id="formId" action="" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" id="eventID_excluir" name="eventID_excluir"/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="modalTitle_excluirs" name="modalTitle_excluirs"/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="eventID" value="eventID_excluir">
                  <button type="submit"  name="desmarcar" onclick="clicked(event)"  id="desmarcar" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><i class="fas fa-calendar-times"></i> Desmarcar Consulta</button>
                  <input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar" class="btn btn-info"></input>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteButton"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Excluir</button>
                  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
               </form>
               <form id="id_do_form_faturar" class="formAjax"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="eventID_faturar_outro"  />
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" style="border:0">Faturar</button>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Qaundo abre a modal usei isso `$('#id_do_form_faturar').attr('data-formid', event.id);` para colocar o id do evento clicado em `data-formid=""`, que fica assim

```
<div id="calendarModal_calendar2" class="modal fade show" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title center">Detalhes da Consulta</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
         </div>
         <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
            <span class="titulo_modal">Título</span>
            <h4 id="modalTitle_excluir" class="modal-title">psico - MANOEL ROZENG DA SILVA - MARIA REGINA DURANTE BAESSO</h4>
            <span class="titulo_modal">Data e Hora</span>
            <div id="modalWhen_excluir" style="margin-top:5px;">Segunda-feira, 28 janeiro 2019, 5:00 - 6:00</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <form role="form" id="formId" action="" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" id="eventID_excluir" name="eventID_excluir" value="1003">
                  <input type="hidden" id="modalTitle_excluirs" name="modalTitle_excluirs">
                  <input type="hidden" id="eventID" value="eventID_excluir">
                  <button type="submit" name="desmarcar" onclick="clicked(event)" id="desmarcar" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><i class="fas fa-calendar-times"></i> Desmarcar Consulta</button>
                  <input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar" class="btn btn-info">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteButton"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Excluir</button>
                  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
               </form>

               <form id="id_do_form_faturar" class="formAjax" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-formid="1003">
                  <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="eventID_faturar_outro" value="1003">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" style="border:0">Faturar</button>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você vai ter que colocar um id de controle aqui também $('#resultado_empresa_'+AQUI)

Comment: tentei assim mas tbm nao deu $('#resultado_empresa_'+event.id)

Comment: edita ai com a estrutura do html para intendermos o que você está fazendo de errado!

Comment: Ao usar id's repetidos em seu código já está errado.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta a estrutura do html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha `$('#resultado_empresa_').attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_'+event.id);` o seletor `$('#resultado_empresa_')` faz a seleção de todos os elementos cujo o id é `resultado_empresa_`.

Sem ter o HTML não da para saber onde está o alvo da ação pretendida. Então posso apenas supor alguns cenários.

Caso `resultado_empresa_` seja o id do `div` do `fullCalendar`, a variavel `this` do evento `eventClick(event, jsEvent, view)` aponta para elemento `div` do gerador do evento. Então você deve usar:

```
$(this).attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_' + event.id);
```

Caso `resultado_empresa_` seja descendente de um `fullCalendar` personalizado...
...use `.children()` caso `resultado_empresa_` seja descendente direto do gerador do evento.

```
$(this).children('#resultado_empresa_').attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_' + event.id);
```

...use `.find()` caso `resultado_empresa_` não seja descendente direto do gerador do evento.

```
$(this).find('#resultado_empresa_').attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_' + event.id);
```

Caso `resultado_empresa_` sejam muitos e estejam espalhados pelo HTML eu sugiro que você crie um atributo personalizado e único, e então use esse atributo como identificador(atributo criado e valorado segundo o seu critério).

```
$('div[/*Seu identificador*/ = /*Seu critério de identificação*/]').attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_' + event.id);
```

Comment: tentei todas as maneiras que vc disse mas não deu certo ainda, editei minha resposta, acho que melhor seria pra mim a última alternativa, mas nao entendi o que coloco em /*Seu identificador*/ = /*Seu critério de identificação*/

Comment: no html deve ter um `<div id="resultado_empresa_">quaquer coisa</div>`. Nesse `div` crie um atributo qualquer. Ex: identificador. Então vai ficar assim `<div id="resultado_empresa_" identificador="Mesbla">quaquer coisa</div>`. OK. Então no script você coloca assim: $('div[identificador = "Mesbla"]').attr('id', 'resultado_empresa_' + event.id);

Comment: Mas sem o HTML fica difícil de lhe ajudar. Faça um exemplo resumido da situação para que possamos compreender o real problema.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com a estrutura do html